# 1つのネットワーク内に2つのルータ

Tags: network

ご教授お願いします｡

同ネットワーク内にルーターが2つあるとします｡
それぞれIPは
RouterA:192.168.1.253/255.255.255.0
RouterB:192.168.1.254/255.255.255.0
とします｡

同ネットワークに機器A､B､Cがあり､それぞれのデフォルトGWが
A:192.168.1.253
B:192.168.1.253
C:192.168.1.254
となっています｡

同じネットワーク内にデフォルトGWが違う設定の機器があることは問題ないのでしょうか｡
RouterA, Bそれぞれ行き着く先は同じネットワークなんですが…

問題無いような気がするのですが､実機検証ができない状態ですので､この場をお借りして質問
しました｡

ご回答よろしくお願いします｡

Comment: 編集でルータのIPアドレスと機器のデフォルトゲートウェイのアドレスが違う物になってしまったので意味不明になっています。元の状態で正しかったのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 確かに意味不明なので、意味が通るように修正しました。質問の意図と合わなければ修正してくださいませ。

Comment: suzukis様、take88様、ありがとうございます。

Comment: 私が勘違いしていました。take88様の修正内容で合っています。

Comment: というか、元のままでよかったですね…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
----+---------------------+-------
    |                     |
    :                     :
  routerA              routerB
    |192.168.1.253        |192.168.1.254
----+--+-------+------+---+--------
       |       |      |
      機器A   機器B   機器C
      (GWはrouterA)  (GWはrouterB)
```

ってことですね。

問題ありません。

ただし、機器A,Bが必ずRouterAを経由する、機器Cが必ずRouterBを経由することは保証されていません。

たとえば別ネットワークの機器Dから機器C宛ての通信がRouterA経由で行われた場合、以後機器Cから機器Dへの通信はRouterAで行われるかもしれません。

---

別ネットワークへの経路になにかあるのかもしれませんし、routerAかBかその両方に、それぞれしか繋がらないネットワークが生えているとかいうこともあるので、一概に意味が無いと決めつけられる物でもありません。

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます｡
なるほどですね｡一度ルーティングテーブルに書き込まれ､その情報を優先にルーティングするという事ですね｡

ただし､｢通常｣という表現が正しいかわかりませんが､上記の場合､ルーターが2つある意味ないような気がします｡
この考え方は的外れではないでしょうか｡

Comment: 別ネットワークからの接続の場合、外部の機器DからrouterAへ到達し、宛先アドレス変換で機器Cに到達した、という場合があると厄介です。機器C→機器Dへはルータを通る必要がありますが、デフォルトGWの他に設定がなければ、レスポンスがrouterB経由になります。機器Dから見ると、routerAを経由した場合と違うホストからパケットが到達したように見えるため、機器Dが最初に送ったパケットと関連付けられず、通信がうまく行えない恐れがあります。

Answer (score 3):

問題無いです。

「ルーターが2つある意味がない」かどうかはわかりません。
何かの設計意図や事情がある（もしくは「あった」）と推測されますので
RouterA、B の設定を違いを確認すると 何かヒントが得られるかもしれませんね。

Comment: take88様コメントありがとうございます。他業者様から頂いたネットワーク構成図が上記のようなものだったので意図を再度確認してみます。ただ技術的に問題ないことが確認できて助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

RouterA, RounterBのIPアドレスの付与の仕方が良くないと思います。
機器A, B, CぞれぞれのIPアドレスとサブネットマスクはどのようになっていますか？
ルーターはそもそもネットワークをセグメントに分けるために設置するので、
RouterAのセグメント内に機器A,BのIPアドレス、
RouterBのセグメント内に機器CのIPアドレスが無いといけません。
例えば、
RouterA:192.168.1.1  サブネットマスク:255.255.255.0
RouterB:192.168.2.1  サブネットマスク:255.255.255.0
機器A:192.168.1.2
機器B:192.168.1.3
機器C:192.168.2.2
のような感じです。

Comment: 申し訳ございません｡
記載が間違っておりました｡
RouterA:192.168.1.253
RouterB:192.168.1.254
です｡

Comment: 全て､サブネットは255.255.255です｡

Answer (score 1):

2台設置されていることは技術的に問題ないのは他の回答の通りです。
その意図は想像するしか無いため、一つ挙げます。

L3の冗長性を確保するためにVRRPが組んである（あった）可能性があります。VRRPが機能していればABCのデフォルトGW‌​は同じ仮想IPアドレスに向ければいいんですが、知らずに各ルータのIPアドレスを設定しているかも知れません。

もちろん、@suzukisさんの回答のように経路のためかも知れません。業者さんの回答を待ちましょう。